# Getting CKEditor to work with Flask Admin

Tags: python, flask, ckeditor, flask-admin

I'm trying to make turn the Flask Admin text box into a CKEdit box, as described here. However, when I run it and go to the existing admin fields it doesn't show any change to the text boxes, and when I run it and go to the TestAdmin field created to demonstrate I get this error:

`OperationalError: (OperationalError) no such table: test u'SELECT count(?) AS count_1 \nFROM test' ('*',)`

Along with a bunch of other traceback messages.

I have changed my init script to be this:

```
import os
from flask import Flask
from flask.ext.sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask.ext.login import LoginManager
from flask.ext.openid import OpenID
from flask.ext.mail import Mail
from config import basedir, ADMINS, MAIL_SERVER, MAIL_PORT, MAIL_USERNAME, MAIL_PASSWORD
from momentjs import momentjs
from flask.ext.babel import Babel
from flask.ext import admin
from flask_admin.contrib.sqla import ModelView
from wtforms import TextAreaField
from wtforms.widgets import TextArea

app = Flask(__name__)

app.config.from_object('config')
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
lm = LoginManager()
lm.init_app(app)
lm.login_view = 'login'
oid = OpenID(app, os.path.join(basedir, 'tmp'))
mail = Mail(app)
babel = Babel(app)

from app import views, models


###
class CKTextAreaWidget(TextArea):
    def __call__(self, field, **kwargs):
        if kwargs.get('class'):
            kwargs['class'] += " ckeditor"
        else:
            kwargs.setdefault('class', 'ckeditor')
        return super(CKTextAreaWidget, self).__call__(field, **kwargs)

class CKTextAreaField(TextAreaField):
    widget = CKTextAreaWidget()


class Test(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    text = db.Column(db.UnicodeText)


class TestAdmin(ModelView):
    form_overrides = dict(text=CKTextAreaField)

    create_template = 'edit.html'
    edit_template = 'edit.html'

admin = admin.Admin(app, name = 'PetroTools', template_mode = 'bootstrap3')
admin.add_view(ModelView(models.Report, db.session))
admin.add_view(ModelView(models.Well, db.session))
admin.add_view(ModelView(models.Field, db.session))
admin.add_view(ModelView(models.Section, db.session))
admin.add_view(TestAdmin(Test, db.session))

if not app.debug:
    import logging
    from logging.handlers import SMTPHandler
    credentials = None
    if MAIL_USERNAME or MAIL_PASSWORD:
        credentials = (MAIL_USERNAME, MAIL_PASSWORD)
    mail_handler = SMTPHandler((MAIL_SERVER, MAIL_PORT), 'no-reply@' + MAIL_SERVER, ADMINS, 'microblog failure', credentials)
    mail_handler.setLevel(logging.ERROR)
    app.logger.addHandler(mail_handler)

if not app.debug:
    import logging
    from logging.handlers import RotatingFileHandler
    file_handler = RotatingFileHandler('tmp/microblog.log', 'a', 1 * 1024 * 1024, 10)
    file_handler.setFormatter(logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s %(levelname)s: %(message)s [in %(pathname)s:%(lineno)d]'))
    app.logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
    file_handler.setLevel(logging.INFO)
    app.logger.addHandler(file_handler)
    app.logger.info('microblog startup')

app.jinja_env.globals['momentjs'] = momentjs
```

and I've put the edit.html file in my `app/templates` folder.

My best guess at why it's not working is that maybe I'm not supposed to put `edit.html` into the templates folder with the other things, but in the flask admin templates folder? But where is that folder? Do I even have one? In `edit.html` it says:

`{% extends 'admin/model/edit.html' %}`

But I don't have that directory. Is that what's screwing it up?

I figure I'm probably doing something pretty stupid due to my lack of understanding of how exactly this thing is trying change the ckeditor template. Can anyone help?

Thanks a lot,
Alex

**Edit:** Here is everything in the edit.html file. I haven't edited the version from github, and I have it in the folder `/app/templates/`.

```
{% extends 'admin/model/edit.html' %}

{% block tail %}
    {{ super() }}
    <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ckeditor/4.0.1/ckeditor.js"></script>
{% endblock %}
```

**Final Edit**:
With Mr Cunningham's help, my final version works and looks like this:

```
import os
from flask import Flask
from flask.ext.sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask.ext.login import LoginManager
from flask.ext.openid import OpenID
from flask.ext.mail import Mail
from config import basedir, ADMINS, MAIL_SERVER, MAIL_PORT, MAIL_USERNAME, MAIL_PASSWORD
from momentjs import momentjs
from flask.ext.babel import Babel

###
from flask.ext import admin
from flask_admin.contrib.sqla import ModelView
from wtforms import TextAreaField
from wtforms.widgets import TextArea
###

app = Flask(__name__)

app.config.from_object('config')
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
lm = LoginManager()
lm.init_app(app)
lm.login_view = 'login'
oid = OpenID(app, os.path.join(basedir, 'tmp'))
mail = Mail(app)
babel = Babel(app)

from app import views, models


###
class CKTextAreaWidget(TextArea):
    def __call__(self, field, **kwargs):
        if kwargs.get('class'):
            kwargs['class'] += " ckeditor"
        else:
            kwargs.setdefault('class', 'ckeditor')
        return super(CKTextAreaWidget, self).__call__(field, **kwargs)

class CKTextAreaField(TextAreaField):
    widget = CKTextAreaWidget()

class TestAdmin(ModelView):
    form_overrides = dict(text=CKTextAreaField)

    create_template = 'edit.html'
    edit_template = 'edit.html'


###ADMIN###
admin = admin.Admin(app, name = 'PetroTools', template_mode = 'bootstrap3')
admin.add_view(TestAdmin(models.Report, db.session))
admin.add_view(TestAdmin(models.Well, db.session))
admin.add_view(TestAdmin(models.Field, db.session))
admin.add_view(TestAdmin(models.Section, db.session))
###########

if not app.debug:
    import logging
    from logging.handlers import SMTPHandler
    credentials = None
    if MAIL_USERNAME or MAIL_PASSWORD:
        credentials = (MAIL_USERNAME, MAIL_PASSWORD)
    mail_handler = SMTPHandler((MAIL_SERVER, MAIL_PORT), 'no-reply@' + MAIL_SERVER, ADMINS, 'microblog failure', credentials)
    mail_handler.setLevel(logging.ERROR)
    app.logger.addHandler(mail_handler)

if not app.debug:
    import logging
    from logging.handlers import RotatingFileHandler
    file_handler = RotatingFileHandler('tmp/microblog.log', 'a', 1 * 1024 * 1024, 10)
    file_handler.setFormatter(logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s %(levelname)s: %(message)s [in %(pathname)s:%(lineno)d]'))
    app.logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
    file_handler.setLevel(logging.INFO)
    app.logger.addHandler(file_handler)
    app.logger.info('microblog startup')

app.jinja_env.globals['momentjs'] = momentjs
```

At first it still wasn't showing text fields as ckedit fields in admin. I got it to work by dropping all the tables and recreating them, and also using db_migrate.py script from Miguel Grinberg's flask tutorial. I also renamed the text field in my `models.py` file from `Text` to `text`, not sure if that had any effect.

Comment: Can you show all of your edit.html.

Comment: Sure, I've added it in there.

Comment: If you comment out the form_overrides in your TestAdmin class what do you get?

Comment: Doesn't seem to change anything - I get the same error.

Comment: Is your database and its tables setup correctly?

Comment: Yes, it all works except when I try to go to the test case in added to Flask Admin.

Comment: I've added a simple example using an in-memory SQLite database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a simple working example using in-memory SQLite. There are only two files, the flask application and the edit Jinja2 html template.

Library versions used are Flask 0.10.1, Flask-SQLAlchemy 2.1 and Flask-Admin 1.4.

The flask application `flask-ckeditor.py` in the root folder:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask.ext.admin import Admin
from flask.ext.admin.contrib.sqla import ModelView
from flask.ext.admin.menu import MenuLink
from flask.ext.sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from wtforms.widgets import TextArea, TextInput
from wtforms.fields import TextAreaField

app = Flask(__name__)

app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///:memory:'
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_ECHO'] = True
app.config['DEBUG'] = True
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'super-secret'

db = SQLAlchemy(app)


class Test(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'tests'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    text = db.Column(db.UnicodeText)


class CKEditorWidget(TextArea):
    def __call__(self, field, **kwargs):
        if kwargs.get('class'):
            kwargs['class'] += " ckeditor"
        else:
            kwargs.setdefault('class', 'ckeditor')
        return super(CKEditorWidget, self).__call__(field, **kwargs)


class CKEditorField(TextAreaField):
    widget = CKEditorWidget()


class TestAdminView(ModelView):
    form_overrides = dict(text=CKEditorField)
    can_view_details = True
    create_template = 'edit.html'
    edit_template = 'edit.html'


@app.route('/')
def index():
    return '<a href="/admin/">Click me to get to Admin!</a>'

# Create admin
admin = Admin(app, name='Admin')
admin.add_view(TestAdminView(model=Test, session=db.session, category='Tables', name='Test'))
admin.add_link(MenuLink(name='Public Website', category='', url='/'))


def build_db():

    tests = [
        {
            'text': "<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut</p>"
        },
        {
            'text': "<p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque<p>"
        },
        {
            'text': "<p>At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis praesentium</p>"
        }
    ]

    db.drop_all()
    db.create_all()

    for test in tests:
        test_db = Test(**test)
        db.session.add(test_db)
    db.session.commit()


@app.before_first_request
def create_user():
    build_db()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

The Jinja2 html template file `templates/edit.html`:

```
{% extends 'admin/model/edit.html' %}

{% block tail %}
    {{ super() }}
    <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ckeditor/4.0.1/ckeditor.js"></script>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Great! It works. Didn't seem to work with existing admin views until I cleared the database and remade it, but now it seems to be working perfectly. Thanks a lot for all the patience and help.

Answer (score 13):

You can use [Flask-CKEditor](https://github.com/greyli/flask-ckeditor). It provide a `CKEditorField` that is exactly what you need. We need to install it first:

```
$ pip install flask-ckeditor
```

Then in your code:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_admin import Admin
from flask_admin.contrib.sqla import ModelView
from flask_ckeditor import CKEditor, CKEditorField  # Step 1

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'dev'
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///'

db = SQLAlchemy(app)
ckeditor = CKEditor(app)  # Step 2

class Post(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = db.Column(db.String(120))
    text = db.Column(db.Text)


# Step 3
class PostAdmin(ModelView):
    form_overrides = dict(text=CKEditorField)
    create_template = 'edit.html'
    edit_template = 'edit.html'

admin = Admin(app, name='Flask-CKEditor demo')
admin.add_view(PostAdmin(Post, db.session))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

In your template (templates/edit.html):

```
<!-- Step 4 -->
{% extends 'admin/model/edit.html' %}

{% block tail %}
    {{ super() }}
    {{ ckeditor.load() }}
    {# 
    If you have set the configuration variables more than CKEDITOR_SERVE_LOCAL and CKEDITOR_PKG_TYPE, 
    or you need to config the CKEditor textarea, use the line below to register the configuration.
    The name value should be the name of the CKEditor form field.
    #}
    {{ ckeditor.config(name='text') }}
{% endblock %}
```

Get this demo application on [GitHub](https://github.com/greyli/flask-ckeditor/tree/master/examples/flask-admin).

Comment: Can you tell me how to simply integrate uploading images in ckeditor with that extension ?

Comment: You  need to also initialize the extension ```from flask_ckeditor import  CKEditorField```, then 

`app = Flask(__name__)
ckeditor = CKEditor(app)
`

Comment: @BeqaBukhradze https://flask-ckeditor.readthedocs.io/en/latest/plugins.html#image-upload