# Flask-Admin: Adding a WYSIWYG editor to an inline model?

Tags: flask, ckeditor, flask-wtforms, flask-admin

Pretty much as the subject has it: I have a Flask-Admin site, and would like to add TinyMCE or CKEditor to a textarea in an inline model.

There are various instructions for adding CKEditor to Flask-Admin in general, e.g. [Flask-Admin and CKEditor WYSIWYG textarea integration](https://gist.github.com/mrjoes/5189850) and [Getting CKEditor to work with Flask-Admin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34971368/getting-ckeditor-to-work-with-flask-admin). I've followed these to create the WTForms widget and field. The inline models don't use edit.html, for pulling in the JS, but I can add it to the master template, though this is not ideal.

But the main issue is how to attach the WTForms field to the Flask-Admin model. The existing instructions have you set a `form_overrides = dict(fieldname=CKTextAreaField)`. But that doesn't work inside `inline_models`. How do I accomplish this?

Comment: I haven't been able to get this to work on inline models. only textarea field online model, but no override to ckeditor fields.

Comment: Did you manage to solve this? I've tried to use example from flask admin page, but it does not work, although ckeditor js is downloaded on browser.

Comment: I'm afraid I haven't figured it out yet. I did try using the flask-ckeditor package, which got me a little bit closer (i.e. the generated HTML looks like it's almost there) but still doesn't work; I posted an Issue to the github page but it hasn't been answered yet. https://github.com/greyli/flask-ckeditor/issues/42

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue a few days ago and managed to solve it by adding this to my view class.

```
class CustomView(ModelView):

    extra_js = ['//cdn.ckeditor.com/4.6.0/standard/ckeditor.js']
    inline_models=[ ( YourModel, dict(
        form_overrides={
            'FieldName':CKTextAreaField
        }
    ))]
```

Assuming that you followed [the flask admin docs tutorial for CKEditor](https://flask-admin.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced/#replacing-individual-form-fields).

inline_models consist of (model, options) pairs. The "options" object is the key here: it accepts most of the form_* attributes that ModelView has.

Comment: Huh, that's interesting. This partially works: It does generate a CKEditor field, but only in inline items that already exist. If I create a new item by hitting the "Add [model]" button, the one (which, of course, is the one where I actually need it) is created without the CKEditor field. Is this how it works in your app?